# Sklearn - price prediction using cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

%matplotlib inline

boston_properties = load_boston()

l_distance = boston_properties['data'][:, np.newaxis, 7]
linreg = LinearRegression()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(l_distance, boston_properties['target'], test_size = 0.3)
y_pred = cross_val_predict(linreg, l_distance, boston_properties.target, cv=5)

plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color='black')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
print(y_pred.shape)
```

The error which I'm receiving is the following:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (152, 1) and (506,)

How can I make this work?

Comment: why do you use `X_test, y_pred` instead of `X_test, y_test` ?

Comment: your error is in this line `y_pred = cross_val_predict(linreg, l_distance, boston_properties.target, cv=5)` and `plt.plot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a `train_test_split`, but you're not using it to train the model. Then you predict on your entire training data, and compare it with `y_test`. This makes no sense. Use these lines instead:

```py
l_distance = boston_properties['data'][:, np.newaxis, 7]
linreg = LinearRegression()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(l_distance,
    boston_properties['target'], test_size = 0.3) # now you have a train/test set
y_pred = cross_val_predict(linreg, X_train, y_train, cv=5) 

plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color='black')
plt.plot(X_train, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**: You can also use this line to make a straight line through your points:

```
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color='black')
plt.plot([X_train[np.argmin(X_train)], X_train[np.argmax(X_train)]],
         [y_pred[np.argmin(X_train)], y_pred[np.argmax(X_train)]],
         color='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate. If could you answer me for one more question. Why this blue line have that weird shape? It's because of data, or I can I do something with this?

Comment: Of course. Here, I made it better. I did it by making a line through the min and max values of X, and their predicted values as the Y.